# ReactiveUI Example with Avalonia : UserControl View not working

Tags: c#, .net-core, mvvm, reactiveui, avaloniaui

I tried to implement [Reactive UI Example](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/compelling-example) using Avalonia with ReactiveUI. The search works, I can print on the console the elements resulting from it and there is a "slot" for each of them in the UI (the lines appear but are empty), but the NuggetDetailView does not show as the list's items.

I have activated View for ViewModel scan in the `Initialize` method of my Avalonia app :

```cs
    public class App : Application
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
            Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterViewsForViewModels(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
        }
    ....
    }
```

I do not get any error so I'm a bit lost on what I did wrong.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Does `App` and your views are is the same project?

Comment: Yes they are indeed, that’s why I expected the scan to work. But I don’t mind adding the class manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembly code scanning is working (at least on this date), but it looks like you are passing the wrong assembly. At the location where you are trying to register the views the calling assembly is `Avalonia.Controls`.

If you're following the example as I did you could use

`Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterViewsForViewModels(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the reflection-based View scanning was not working.
I changed

```cs
Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterViewsForViewModels(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
```

to

```cs
Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new NugetDetailsView(), typeof(IViewFor<NugetDetailsViewModel>));
```

And it worked

Comment: The assembly scanning code seems to be quite straightforward https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/0518c2bc9e03328712bf1fb2e35bca3dfe5f9885/src/ReactiveUI/Mixins/DependencyResolverMixins.cs#L74-L103 The automatic registrations should totally work if your views implement `IViewFor` or inherit from `ReactiveUserControl` or `ReactiveWindow`

Comment: My control extends `ReactiveUserControl`